# Reset Button on Dell PowerConnect 5324

Tags: networking, dell, switch, dell-powerconnect

The instructions for this switch say about the reset button on the front of the switch:

> "The reset button, located on the
>   front panel, manually resets the
>   device."

Well thanks Dell :-)  Is a reset the same as the 'reload' command on Cisco, or does this reset in the sense the startup config will be restored to factory defaults?  If it is just a reload in the Cisco sense, does anyone know how I restore this switch to factory defaults without the username and password?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it in the manual.  I need to go into the 'startup menu', I do this by hitting enter during the bootup of the switch when it says 'Hit enter or Escape'.  I can then reset that password, or erase the config file on the flash.

Comment: I used this same procedure to make sure everything was set to factory defaults when I got my 5324 off ebay.

Answer (score 3):

From [fixya.com](http://www.fixya.com/support/t2505648-need_set_factory_default_dell)

Connect to the console port via hyperterminal or similar.

Then, at the command prompt... (hit enter twice!)

```
enable
delete startup-config
reload
```

...then say yes to the confirmation request - switch will reboot with no config information....no username/password/IPaddress etc etc.

According to [this thread on the dell forums](http://en.community.dell.com/forums/t/19318506.aspx#19643819), you will need: an **RS-232 crossover cable**

Comment: Doesn't actually help unless I have the password I think...

Comment: Oh, unless the console never asks for a password to go into enable mode?  I guess this would work, I tested my answer below though so I know that works.

Comment: I didn't mention booting it? I just assumed.. you know what they say!